# I have an error in mysql function

Tags: mysql, function, date

This is giving error 1064, borrower is a table and dataofissue is date of issue, rollno is roll no from the borrower table:

```
create function get_info(roll in integer,name in varchar(20))
    -> return boolean
    -> begin
    -> set @date1=curdate()
    -> set @date2:=select dataofissue from borrower where rollin=roll and nameofbook=name
    -> select DATEDIFF(@date1,@date2) into @date3 from borrower
    -> select @date3
    -> if(@date3>15)
    -> return (false)
    -> else
    -> return (true)
    -> end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use a `SELECT` query as a value, you have to put it in parentheses:

```
set @date2:=(select dataofissue from borrower where rollin=roll and nameofbook=name)
```

Or you can use `INTO` to assign the variable:

```
select dataofissue INTO @date2 from borrower where rollin=roll and nameofbook=name
```

Also, you need `;` after each statement in the function. To prevent this from ending the function definition immediately, you have to use a `DELIMITER` directive before defining the function, and use that delimiter to end the function.

`IF` needs `THEN` and `END IF`.

You can't specify `IN`, `OUT`, or `INOUT` for function parameters, that's only for procedures.

```
DELIMITER $
create function get_info(roll integer, name varchar(20)) return boolean
begin
    set @date1=curdate();
    set @date2:=(select dataofissue from borrower where rollin=roll and nameofbook=name);
    select DATEDIFF(@date1,@date2) into @date3;
    if (@date3>15)
    then return (false);
    else return (true);
    end if;
end$
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in integer,name in varchar(20)) return boolean
begin
    set @date1=curdate();
 ' at line 1

Comment: Functions don't have `IN` and `OUT` parameters. All parameters are input, so you can't put that there.